# LocalStorage JS - is it safe to store data to keep persistent after refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Question if I store something that is not related to the user but more for displaying some data and keeping them persistent. is it still unsafe?

For example, I have some suggested locations and each of them is a button with the name of that location. The user can choose which locations to go to.

Please, let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Its a good place to store some persist data, but if you need store some secure use session storage or additional encryption for your sensitive data.

Also you could use storage like indexdb for queries or abstraction over filesystem to store some large

Comment: So, in my case, it's fine if I use localStorage or shall I switch to something more secure?

Comment: If it's just display preferences localStorage is fine for your requirements. Storage is sandboxed so that it can't be read by any other domain except for the site you're accessing.

Comment: thanks, but I was worried that someone can debug it and see through it.